# Neo4j: optimum path search

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Having a graph of people who like rated movies, I would like to extract for each pair of people their highest rated movie. I'm using the following query which requires sorting movies on their rate for each pair of people.

```
MATCH (p1:People) -[:LIKES]-> (m:Movie) <-[:LIKES]- (p2:People) WHERE id(p1) < id(p2)
WITH p1, p2, m ORDER BY m.Rating desc
RETURN p1, p2, head(collect(m) as best
```

I can put movie rating (1/rating or maxRating-rating) into :LIKES relationships, which hence let me identify which movie is in the top rating of both people.

```
MATCH (p1:People), (p2:People) call apoc.algo.dijkstra(p1, p2, 'LIKES', 'rating') YIELD path as path, weight as weight return path, weight
```

Is there a way to use a Dijkstra-like algorithm which would find the allOptimumPath through highest scored nodes to improve the performance of my first query and return paths rather than their starting, middle and ending nodes ?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution which preserves the path rather than reporting extracted nodes.

```
MATCH path=(p1:People) -[:LIKES]-> (m:Movie) <-[:LIKES]- (p2:People) 
WHERE id(p1) < id(p2)
WITH head(nodes(p)) as p1, last(nodes(p)) as p2, path 
ORDER BY m.Rating desc
WITH p1, p2, head(collect(p)) as optPath
RETURN optPath
```